# SharePoint group task notification with elevated permissions

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email, groups, approval-process

On my SharePoint Site are more different Lists with their own permissions. But the Workflow has to write and read in all Lists. Because of this position I grant the Workflow Full Control permissions [HowTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/office/jj822159%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

After that I get the following Problem:

In the first step of the workflow I assign a task to a SharePoint group. All of the persons in the group will get a notification for the created task.

If I am going to set the workflow with the Full Control rights it means that all steps a build to the "app step" in the SharePoint Designer. Nobody gets a email when I start the workflow and a task is created.

Did anyone has the same problem and can get me a answer?

The Problem is, that the task which will be created has to notify more than I person.

It seems the Workflow app can not read the SharePoint Group members?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

For task notifications to groups you have to set the group readable for all users.